# Describe the invariant bilinear maps on the linear group

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, multilinear-algebra

Apologies if this is a stupid question ; it is at least a natural question. Let $V$ be a finite dimensional space over $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$. Denote by ${\mathcal L}(V)$ the vector space of all endomorphisms of $V$ ; it has dimension $n^2$, where $n={\sf dim}(V)$. Also, denote by ${\cal B}(V)$ the space of all bilinear maps
${\mathcal L}(V) \times {\mathcal L}(V) \to {\mathcal L}(V)$ (this has dimension $n^6$). Say that a $b\in {\cal B}(V\times V,V)$ is **invariant** if it satisfies

$$
b({g}^{-1}f_1g,{g}^{-1}f_2g)={g}^{-1}b(f_1,f_2)g 
$$
for any invertible $g\in{\mathcal L}(V)$ and any $f_1,f_2 \in {\mathcal L}(V)$. Clearly the invariant bilinear maps form a subspace of ${\cal B}(V)$, let us denote it by ${\cal I}(V)$.

For $n=2$, I computed a basis of ${\cal I}(V)$ and found that ${\cal I}(V)$ has dimension $7$ (see update below).

In general, is the dimension of ${\cal I}(V)$ known? Or even better, a simple description of the elements of ${\cal I}(V)$, or of some basis of it ?

**Update 10/15/2002**  As requested in a comment, more details when $n=2$ : in this case ${\cal I}(V)$ has a basis made up of six “simply described” elements and a complicated seventh one :

$$
\begin{array}{ccl}
b_1(f,g)&=&fg \\ 
b_2(f,g)&=&gf \\ 
b_3(f,g)&=&{\sf tr}(f)g \\
 b_4(f,g)&=&{\sf tr}(g)f \\ 
 b_5(f,g)&=&{\sf tr}(f){\sf tr}(g){\mathbf{id}}_V \\
b_6(f,g)&=& {\sf tr}(fg) {\mathbf{id}}_V
\end{array}
$$

and the seventh one can be defined in terms of matrices :

$$
b_7\Bigg(
\left(\begin{matrix}
x_{11} & x_{12} \\
x_{21} & x_{22} \\
\end{matrix}\right),
\left(\begin{matrix}
y_{11} & y_{12} \\
y_{21} & y_{22} \\
\end{matrix}\right)
\Bigg)=\left(\begin{matrix}
x_{21}y_{12}-x_{12}y_{21} & (y_{11}-y_{22})x_{12}-(x_{11}-x_{22})y_{12} \\
 -(y_{11}-y_{22})x_{21}+(x_{11}-x_{22})y_{21} & -x_{21}y_{12}+x_{12}y_{21} \\
\end{matrix}\right)
$$

**Edit 24/10/2012**  : Some mildly incorrect statements corrected above.

Comment: Absolutely not a stupid question.. Can you help us with the computed case of $n=2$?

Comment: @Berci : maybe not stupid, but definitely the kind of thing one expects to be studied already (hence the reference-request tag). I’ll post the details on $n=2$ when I have the time. The $n=3$ case should be computable also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link provided by Mariano Suarez-Alvarez [online](http://www.math.unibas.ch/~kraft/Papers/KP-Primer.pdf) answers most of what can be asked on this theme.

Here, I’ll try to provide an elementary proof for the specific question in the OP. 
The result is that for $n\geq 2$, ${\cal I}(V)$ always has dimension six and has a basis $b_1,b_2, \ldots b_6$ as described  in the update in the OP (so $b_7$ is exceptional and only exists in dimension $2$).

Now fix a basis $(v_1,v_2, \ldots ,v_n)$ of $V$. Let $({v_1}^{*},{v_2}^{*}, \ldots ,{v_n}^{*})$ denote the dual basis in $V^*$, and put $e_{ij}(x)={v_i}^{*}(x)e_j$. Then the $e_{ij}$ form a basis for ${\cal L}(V)$, which we call $\cal E$.

We will now use the invariance property, making some special endomorphisms act on $V$ and hence on ${\cal L}(V) \otimes {\cal L}(V)$ (let us denote this space by ${\cal T}(V)$ ; then ${\cal E}\otimes{\cal E}=\lbrace e \otimes f | e,f \in {\cal E} \rbrace$ is a basis of this space).

Let $p_1,p_2, \ldots ,p_r$ be distinct primes (so that no nontrivial multiplicative relation exists between them), and let $d$ be the diagonal endormorphism defined by $d(v_i)=p_iv_i$. Then $d$ also acts diagonally on ${\cal L}(V)$ and ${\cal T}(V)$ : we have

$$
\begin{array}{c}
d^{-1}e_{ij}d=\frac{p_j}{p_i}e_{ij}, \\ 
(d^{-1}e_{ij}d) \otimes  (d^{-1}e_{kl}d)=\frac{p_jp_l}{p_ip_k}(e_{ij} \otimes e_{kl})
\end{array}
$$

The eigenspaces for the action of $d$ on ${\cal L}(V)$  are (from now on $i,j,k,l$ etc always denote different indices ) :

For the eigenvalue $1$, the $n$-dimensional subspace $V_1={\sf Vect}(e_{xx})_{1 \leq x \leq n}$

For the eigenvalue $\frac{p_j}{p_i}$, the $1$-dimensional subspace $V_2(i,j)={\sf Vet}(e_{ij})$.

The eigenspaces for the action of $d$ on ${\cal T}(V)$  are :

For the eigenvalue $1$, the $n^2$-dimensional subspace $W_1$.

For the eigenvalue $\frac{p_j}{p_i}$, the $4(n-1)$-dimensional subspace $W_2(i,j)$

For the eigenvalue $\frac{p_j^2}{p_i^2}$  the one-dimensional subspace $W_3(i,j)$.

For the eigenvalue $\frac{p_jp_k}{p_i^2}$  the two-dimensional subspace $W_4(i,j,k)$.

For the eigenvalue $\frac{p_k^2}{p_ip_j}$  the two-dimensional subspace $W_5(i,j,k)$.

For the eigenvalue $\frac{p_jp_l}{p_ip_k}$  the four-dimensional subspace $W_6(i,j,k,l)$, where

$$
\begin{array}{lcl}
W_1 &=& {\sf Vect}(e_{xx} \otimes e_{xx})_{1 \leq x \leq n} \oplus {\sf Vect}(e_{xx} \otimes e_{yy},\ e_{xy} \otimes e_{yx})_{1 \leq x \neq y \leq n} \\
W_2(i,j) &=& W_{2,1}(i,j) \oplus W_{2,2}(i,j) \\
& & W_{2,1} (i,j)={\sf Vect}(e_{ii} \otimes e_{ij},e_{ij} \otimes e_{ii},e_{ij} \otimes e_{jj},e_{jj} \otimes e_{ij}) \\
& & W_{2,2} (i,j)={\sf Vect}(e_{ij} \otimes e_{xx},e_{xx} \otimes e_{ij},e_{ix} \otimes e_{xj},e_{xj} \otimes e_{ix},
)_{x \in [1…n] \setminus \lbrace i,j \rbrace} \\
W_3(i,j) &=& {\sf Vect}(e_{ij} \otimes e_{ij}) \\
W_4(i,j,k) &=& {\sf Vect}(e_{ij} \otimes e_{ik},e_{ik} \otimes e_{ij}) \\
W_5(i,j,k) &=& {\sf Vect}(e_{ik} \otimes e_{jk},e_{jk} \otimes e_{ik}) \\
W_6(i,j,k,l) &=& {\sf Vect}(e_{ij} \otimes e_{kl},e_{il} \otimes e_{kj},e_{kj} \otimes e_{il},e_{kl} \otimes e_{ij}) \\
\end{array}
$$

By hypothesis, $b$ commutes with the action of $d$, so

$$
(1) \ b(W_1) \subseteq V_1, \ b(W_2(i,j)) \subseteq V_2(i,j),\ b=0 \ \text{on all the} \ W_3,W_4,W_5,W_6.
$$

This yields a special constraint on the form of each of the $n^4$ individual maps $f(e_{t_1t_2} \otimes e_{t_3t_4})$. Those constraints can be refined further by considering the following : for $A\subseteq {\cal L}(V)$ let $S(A)$ denote the stabilizer of $A$  in $L(V)$, i.e.

$$
S(A)=\Bigg\lbrace s \in L(V) \Bigg| \ \forall a\in A, \ \ sa=as \Bigg\rbrace
$$

Then any $s\in S(\lbrace e_{t_1t_2},e_{t_3t_4} \rbrace)$ fixes the element $e_{t_1t_2} \otimes e_{t_3t_4}$. We deduce that not only $f(e_{t_1t_2} \otimes e_{t_3t_4})$ must inhabit the space assigned to him by (1), it must also be in the set $ S'(\lbrace e_{t_1t_2},e_{t_3t_4} \rbrace)
$ of endomorphisms fixed by all the invertible elements of $S(\lbrace e_{t_1t_2},e_{t_3t_4} \rbrace)$. So we need to compute $S(\lbrace e_{t_1t_2},e_{t_3t_4} \rbrace)$ and $S'(\lbrace e_{t_1t_2},e_{t_3t_4} \rbrace)$ in general : a straightforward set of linear algebra computations shows that

$$
\begin{array}{lcl}
S(e_{ii}) &=& {\sf Vect}(e_{ii}) \oplus {\sf Vect} (e_{xy})_{x\neq i,y \neq i} \\
S(e_{ij}) &=& {\sf Vect}(e_{ii}+e_{jj}) \oplus {\sf Vect} (e_{xy})_{x\neq j,y \neq i} \\
S(\lbrace e_{ii},e_{jj} \rbrace) &=& {\sf Vect}(e_{ii},e_{jj}) \oplus {\sf Vect} (e_{xy})_{x\not\in \lbrace i,j \rbrace, y \not\in \lbrace i,j \rbrace } \\
S(\lbrace e_{ii},e_{ij} \rbrace) &=& {\sf Vect}(e_{ii}+e_{jj}) \oplus {\sf Vect} (e_{xy})_{x\neq i, y \not\in \lbrace i,j \rbrace } \\
S(\lbrace e_{ii},e_{ji} \rbrace) &=& {\sf Vect}(e_{ii}+e_{jj}) \oplus {\sf Vect} (e_{xy})_{x\not\in \lbrace i,j \rbrace , y\neq i} \\
S(\lbrace e_{ij},e_{ji} \rbrace) &=& {\sf Vect}(e_{ii}+e_{jj}) \oplus {\sf Vect} (e_{xy})_{x\not\in \lbrace i,j \rbrace , y\not\in \lbrace i,j \rbrace } \\
S(\lbrace e_{ij},e_{kk} \rbrace) &=& {\sf Vect}(e_{ii}+e_{jj},e_{kk}) \oplus {\sf Vect} (e_{xy})_{x\not\in \lbrace j,k \rbrace , y\not\in \lbrace i,k \rbrace } \\
S(\lbrace e_{ij},e_{jk} \rbrace) &=& {\sf Vect}(e_{ii}+e_{jj}+e_{kk}
) \oplus {\sf Vect} (e_{xy})_{x\not\in \lbrace i,j \rbrace , y\neq k} \\
\end{array}
$$

and hence

$$
\begin{array}{lcl}
S'(e_{ii}) &=& {\sf Vect}(e_{ii},{\sf id}_V) \\
S'(e_{ij}) &=& {\sf Vect}(e_{ii},e_{jj},e_{ij},{\sf id}_V) \\
S'(\lbrace e_{ii},e_{jj} \rbrace) &=& {\sf Vect}(e_{ii},e_{jj},{\sf id}_V) \\
S'(\lbrace e_{ii},e_{ij} \rbrace) &=& {\sf Vect}(e_{ii},e_{ij},e_{ji},e_{jj},{\sf id}_V) \\
S'(\lbrace e_{ii},e_{ji} \rbrace) &=& {\sf Vect}(e_{ii},e_{ij},e_{ji},e_{jj},{\sf id}_V) \\
S'(\lbrace e_{ij},e_{ji} \rbrace) &=& {\sf Vect}(e_{ii},e_{ij},e_{ji},e_{jj},{\sf id}_V) \\
S'(\lbrace e_{ij},e_{kk} \rbrace) &=& {\sf Vect}(e_{ii}+e_{jj},e_{ij},e_{kk},{\sf id}_V)  \\
S'(\lbrace e_{ij},e_{jk} \rbrace) &=& {\sf Vect}(e_{jj},e_{ij},e_{ik},e_{jk},{\sf id}_V) \\
\end{array}
$$

Combining the two constraints, we obtain the following : there are structure constants $a_1,a_2, \ldots, a_{16}$ such that for any distinct $i,j,k$

$$
\begin{array}{lcl}
b(e_{ii} \otimes e_{ii}) &=& a_1e_{ii}+a_2{\sf id}_V \\
b(e_{ii} \otimes e_{jj}) &=& a_3e_{ii}+a_4e_{jj}+a_5{\sf id}_V \\
b(e_{ij} \otimes e_{ji}) &=& a_6e_{ii}+a_7e_{jj}+a_{8}{\sf id}_V \\
b(e_{ii} \otimes e_{ij}) &=& a_{9}e_{ij} \\
b(e_{ij} \otimes e_{ii}) &=& a_{10}e_{ij} \\
b(e_{ij} \otimes e_{jj}) &=& a_{11}e_{ij} \\
b(e_{jj} \otimes e_{ij}) &=& a_{12}e_{ij} \\
b(e_{ij} \otimes e_{kk}) &=& a_{13}e_{ij} \\
b(e_{kk} \otimes e_{ij}) &=& a_{14}e_{ij} \\
b(e_{ij} \otimes e_{jk}) &=& a_{15}e_{ik}\\
b(e_{jk} \otimes e_{ij}) &=& a_{16}e_{ik} \\
b(e \otimes f) &=& 0 \ \text{for all the other } \ e \otimes f \ \text{in the canonical basis.}
\end{array}
$$

( those structure constants should depend on the indices $i,j,k$ a priori, but the invariance by permutation matrices allows us to see they do not).

If we write out the invariance with respect to the action of the transvection $p={\sf id}_V+te_{12}$, we see that we can express linearly $a_{8},a_9,a_{10},a_{11},a_{12}$ in terms of $a_1,a_2 \ldots a_7$  (I omit some computational details here).

In dimension $2$, this is sufficient since we already have seven independent maps ($b_1$ to $b_7$ as in the OP).

In dimension $n \geq 3$, similarly we can write out the invariance with respect to endomorphisms of the form ${\sf id}_V+ue_{12}+ve_{13}+we_{23}$, and this way we can express all the $a_i$ linearly in terms of $a_1,a_2, \ldots ,a_6$ only.

Since we already have six independent solutions ($b_1$ to $b_6$ as in the OP), this concludes the proof.